# Unit testing with `testthat` on functions that write/read files, or a Fortran error

Tags: r, unit-testing, fortran, testthat

What is the best way to make unit testing with `testthat` on functions that read and write files?

Apologies for asking a complicated question, but I am not sure what is wrong here.

I have implemented a number of functions in Fortran, that reads and writes files. They are compiled in an R package cf. Writing R Extension manual. My unit testing with `testthat` generates random content that is written to temporary files with tempfile(). Running R CMD check on the R package works on my local Windows machine.

Running with R-devel fails however because it cannot detect Rtools for R-3.5.0 (devel). So I submitted to win-builder.

http://win-builder.r-project.org/ however fails with the following error:

```
  At line 9 of file auxil.f95
Fortran runtime error: Actual string length is shorter than the declared one for dummy argument 'fn' (96/255)
```

with corresponding Fortran source:

```
subroutine get_nlines(fn, nlines, stat) !line 9
  implicit none

  !! Arguments
  character(255), intent(in) :: fn
  integer, intent(out) :: nlines, stat

  !! Local variables
  character(len=1) :: one

  nlines = 0
  open(40, file=fn, status='OLD')
  do
    read(40, *, iostat=stat) one
    if (stat /= 0) exit
    nlines = nlines + 1
  end do
  close(40)

end subroutine
```

The Fortran code is stored in the `src` subdirectory of the R package, and is called with

```
get_nlines <- function(fn) {
  stopifnot(file.exists(fn))
  res <- .Fortran('get_nlines', fn=as.character(fn), nlines=integer(1), stat=integer(1))
  if (res$nlines == 0 & res$stat != 0) {
    warning(paste0('get_nlines did not read lines; IOSTAT error ', res$stat, '.'))
    return(structure(NA, code=res$stat))
  }
  res$nlines
}
```

So there it is. 
I don't know if my Fortran code is wrong, or if it's something that occurs on the win-builder server.

Comment: Where is your Fortran code? How do you call that subroutine? What you show is simply not complete.

Comment: OK, and what do you pass as `fn` to that R code? Please, we need to see where those things come from. Really, this is *not* enough. We just know that `fn` must have 255 characters.

Comment: How do you call `testthat`? How does the code which causes the error shown look like? We are simply missing any code that causes the error.

Comment: `fn` is a character vector returned from `tempfile()`, and contains the path to the filename.
The `testthat` is called using `test_check(<packagename>)`.

Comment: Than `fn` must be 255 character longs. Why is it written that way and not as `character(*)` I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

*"I don't know if my Fortran code is wrong"* I still simply don't understand from your question if the code you have shown is "the" your code or if it is inside some R package you are using.

If it is the Fortran code you are speaking about (you didn't show anything else), then you should try `character(*)` instead of `character(255)`, because there is no apparent reason for the exact fixed length 255. That is exactly what the error message complains about, that `fn` is not exactly 255 chars long as you require in `get_nlines()`.

Comment: I've been using `character(255)` as this is the (maximum) length character that R can pass to and from Fortran.

Comment: It is not a good choice, even it there is such a maximum, it is not relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, where you offer no insight into what or why it is bad choice. Using an assumed length character variable (`character(*)`) just made it worse, as the strings Fortran received was incorrectly truncated. I will attempt to do the opposite now; padding all strings to 255 characters with space.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no reason for such irony. I was trying to help, but help yourself.